# Multiline PHP BB Code

Tags: php, regex, multiline, bbcode

I can't work out how to get my Regex to select multiple lines, when I'm using

```
[b]Test[/b]
```

my BB code works fine but when I try

```
[b]
Test
[/b]
```

I have read that I should use the modifiers `/s /m` in my regex but I don't know how to, I have tried: preg_match_all('`\[(' . $tags . ')=?(.*?)\](.+?)\[/\1\]/m/s`' but it doesnt work.

Any Suggestions?

Working example:

```
$tags = 'b|i|size|color|center|quote|url|img';
while (preg_match_all('`\[(' . $tags . ')=?(.*?)\](.+?)\[/\1\]`', $string, $matches))
    foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $match) {
        list($tag, $param, $innertext) = array($matches[1][$key], $matches[2][$key], $matches[3][$key]);
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is all it takes, but you are missing an opening delimiter (another `/`) and applying multiple modifiers works without additional slashes: `'/.../ms'`

Comment: Oh, I see. Your delimiters are `\``. In that case, you don't need slashes at all, just do: `'\`\[(' . $tags . ')=?(.*?)\](.+?)\[/\1\]\`ms'`

Comment: I'll make that a proper answer then.

Comment: Whats the difference between using ` and / ? could you show me and example where only / are used.

Comment: wait a minute for my answer, I'll include it

Comment: See also the manual on regex delimiters http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php - just note the flags after `/` or `#` or your backtick, regardless. You could also use the alternative syntax `(?s)` as mentioned in http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.internal-options.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for adding modifiers is not right. Firstly, you do not need any slashes to apply them. They just belong after the delimiter (which in your case is not `/` but `` ` ``). And also you do not need to delimit every single modifier again, just stick them together:

```
'`\[(' . $tags . ')=?(.*?)\](.+?)\[/\1\]`ms'
```

Which delimiter you use does not matter at all. Check out [PHP documentation on delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). You can use

> any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.

Just be careful that the delimiter has to be escaped. So there is no difference between `` ` `` and `/` at all. Just if you use `/` instead, then you need to escape `/` within the regex (otherwise PHP will assume that this is the end of the regex). Like this:

```
'/\[(' . $tags . ')=?(.*?)\](.+?)\[\/\1\]/ms'
```

Therefore, the choice of delimiter is mostly a matter of convenience - use one that does not occur within the regex if possible, so you do not have to escape it. `/` is simply the most common choice, which is why you have probably found the `/m` notation for adding modifiers. As the PHP documentation states are common choices are `#` and `~` (I have also seen `!` quite often).